# Why does my web API post method get null parameter when the collection size is more than 15k?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have web api post method which accepts a complex object as parameter from body. Class object has one generic collection property when the size of the collection exceeds 15k I get parameter value as `null`.

I have tried setting requestfiltering in `web.config` of asp.net mvc and web api project.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Web api method call is made from asp.net mvc application through ajax request like shown in below code snippet

```
TestWebAPIPostMethod: function (item) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: 'web api url',
                async: false,
                headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
                crossDomain: true,                
                error: function () {
                },
                success: function () {
                }
            });
        }
```

I have this setting in `web.config`:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="8675309" />
```

My collection size might be up to 100k. Is there any setting which I'm missing?

Comment: Is there a maxRequestLength set in the web.config under httpruntime?  Maybe that need to be increased

Comment: Thanks Ken Tucker! I have this setting in web.config  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/> still same issue